# Pandas dataframe - speed in python: dataframe operations, numba, cython

Tags: python, performance, pandas, cython, numba

I have a financial dataset with ~2 million rows. I would like to import it as a pandas dataframe and add additional columns by applying rowwise functions utilizing some of the existing column values. For this purpose I would like to not use any techniques like parallelization, hadoop for python, etc, and so I'm faced with the following:

I am already doing this similar to the example below and performance is poor, ~24 minutes to just get through ~20K rows. *Note: this is not the actual function, it is completely made up.* For the additional columns I am calculating various financial option metrics. I suspect the slow speed is primarily due to iterating over all the rows, not really the functions themselves as they are fairly simple (e.g. calculating price of an option). I know I can speed up little things in the functions themselves, such as using erf instead of the normal distribution, but for this purpose I want to focus on the holistic problem itself.

```
def func(alpha, beta, time, vol):
    px = (alpha*beta)/time * vol
    return px

# Method 1 (could also use itertuples here) - this is the one that takes ~24 minutes now
for row in df.iterrows():
    df['px'][row] = func(alpha, beta, df['time'][row], df['vol'][row])
```

I have also tried vectorizing this but keep getting an error about 'cannot serialize float' or something like that.

**My thought is to try one of the following methods, and I am not sure which one would theoretically be fastest? Are there non-linearities associated with running these, such that a test with 1000 rows would not necessarily indicate which would be fastest across all 2 million rows?** Probably a separate question, but should I focus on more efficient ways to manage the dataset rather than just focus on applying the functions?

```
# Alternative 1 (df.apply with existing function above)
df['px'] = df.apply(lambda row: func(alpha, beta, row['time'], row['vol']), axis=1)

# Alternative 2 (numba & jit)
@jit
def func(alpha, beta, time, vol):
    px = (alpha*beta)/time * vol
    return px

# Alternative 3 (cython)
def func_cython(double alpha, double beta, double time, double vol):
    cdef double px
    px = (alpha*beta)/time * vol
    return px
```

In the case of Cython and numba, would I still iterate over all the rows using df.apply? Or is there a more efficient way?

I have referenced the following and found them to be helpful in understanding the various options, but not what the 'best' way is to do this (though I suppose it depends ultimately on the application).

https://lectures.quantecon.org/py/need_for_speed.html

[Numpy vs Cython speed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7799977/numpy-vs-cython-speed)

[Speeding up a numpy loop in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24071531/speeding-up-a-numpy-loop-in-python?noredirect=1&lq=1)

[Cython optimization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38129097/cython-optimization)

http://www.devx.com/opensource/improve-python-performance-with-cython.html

Comment: "I have also tried vectorizing this but keep getting an error about 'cannot serialize float' or something like that." is what you should fix, so that you could `df['px']  = func(alpha, beta, df['time'], df['vol'])`.

Comment: Could you include a minimal example so that we can **reproduce** the "cannot serialize float" problem? That will likely also impact any solution using numba or cython because these require correct types for best execution speed.

Comment: Yes sure will do, will not be for a few hours though. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about simply:

```
df.loc[:, 'px'] = (alpha * beta) / df.loc[:, 'time'] * df.loc[:, 'vol']
```

By the way, your for-loop/lambda solutions are slow because the overhead for each pandas access is large. So accessing each cell separately (via looping over each row) is much slower than accessing the whole column.

Comment: Slightly faster/more idiomatic to write single column access as `df['px']`, etc.

Comment: @chrisb I prefer using `df.loc[row, col]` explicitly and consistently. As `df[]` may cause problem with chained indexing when setting values.